# Directive to create flash alerts

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, flash

I'd like to add flash alerts on my angular. I mean by this simple messages which fade in/out when the user execute an action to notify him his action is done.

To do this, I have created a directive with the template to use:

```
startupjobsApp.directive('flashAlert', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',

    templateUrl: 'flash-tpl',

    replace: true,

    link: function (scope, element) {
            scope.text = 'action complete';
            scope.isVisible = false;
        }
  };
});
```

My template:

```
<div ng-show="isVisible == true" class="flash" ng-animate="{show: 'fadeIn', hide:'fadeOut'}">{{text}}</div>
```

With the following CSS:

```
.fadeIn-setup,.fadeOut-setup {
  -webkit-transition: 1s linear opacity;
  -moz-transition: 1s linear opacity;
  -o-transition: 1s linear opacity;
  transition: 1s linear opacity;
}
.fadeIn-setup{
  opacity:0;
}
.fadeOut-setup{
  opacity:1;
}
.fadeIn-setup.fadeIn-start {
  opacity: 1;
}
.fadeOut-setup.fadeOut-start{
    opacity:0;
}
```

Basically when a user click on a button I'd like to be able to pass the text to my directive so it can be customized and show my alert for a few seconds with a fade in/out effect.

However I can't managed to pass the data text and isVisbile properly from my controllers to my directive.
What are the best practices to do this?

Many thanks

Comment: It looks like you don't have a strong understanding of how scopes are supposed to interact with directives. Check out the http://egghead.io videos and look at the [directive guide](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).

Answer (score 1):

Use a service to pass these values.

I would do it like this (coffeescript):

```
  .factory('flashMessageService', [()->
    message: ''

    setMessage: (message)->
      @message = message

    getMessage: ()->
      return message

  ])
```

Then in your directive, set up a watch, like this (remember to inject `flashMessageService` into the directive) inside the directive's **link** function:

```
scope.$watch(
  ()->
    fashMessageService.getMessage()
  , 
  (newMessage)->
    if newMessage.body isnt ''

      scope.text = message
      scope.isVisible = true

      # set a timeout to remove it afterwards.
      $timeout(
        ()-> 
          scope.isVisible = false;
          scope.text = '';
        , 
        5000
      )
)
```

Then to display a message, you simply use:

```
flashMessageService.setMessage("This is a test message!")
```

You can inject flashMessageService wherever you like.

*P.S.*: This is slightly over-simplified. If you were to call this twice, once 4 seconds after the initial call, your second message would disappear when the first was scheduled to.

I have implemented something similar myself, and I found it useful to display a list of messages, with each item in the list being displayed for 5 seconds before it is removed. Thay way it's hard to accidentally code messages that the user can easily miss.